# Tablesorter plugin not working on loading html code for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

When I try to use the tablesorter plugin with direct HTML it works.

For direct I mean:

```
 echo '<div id="content"><table cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">             
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>first name</th> 
                <th>last name</th> 
                <th>age</th> 
                <th>total</th> 
                <th>discount</th> 
                <th>date</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            <tr> 
                <td>peter</td> 
                <td>parker</td> 
                <td>28</td> 
                <td>$9.99</td> 
                <td>20%</td> 
                <td>jul 6, 2006 8:14 am</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>john</td> 
                <td>hood</td> 
                <td>33</td> 
                <td>$19.99</td> 
                <td>25%</td> 
                <td>dec 10, 2002 5:14 am</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>clark</td> 
                <td>kent</td> 
                <td>18</td> 
                <td>$15.89</td> 
                <td>44%</td> 
                <td>jan 12, 2003 11:14 am</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>bruce</td> 
                <td>almighty</td> 
                <td>45</td> 
                <td>$153.19</td> 
                <td>44%</td> 
                <td>jan 18, 2001 9:12 am</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td>bruce</td> 
                <td>evans</td> 
                <td>22</td> 
                <td>$13.19</td> 
                <td>11%</td> 
                <td>jan 18, 2007 9:12 am</td> 
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table></div>';
```

But when this code is loaded with JavaScript from a navigation code:

```
$(".menu_user").live('click', function() {
    $('.menu_user_sel').removeClass('menu_user_sel').addClass('menu_user');
    $(this).removeClass('menu_user').addClass('menu_user_sel');
    var goPage = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#content').load(goPage + ".php");


});
```

Which loads this php code:

```
echo '</br>';
echo '<div id="cercaDiv" name="cercaDiv">';
echo '<input type="text" name="cerca" id="cerca"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="bottoni" name="bottoni">';
echo '<input id="nuovoUtente" type="button" value="">';
echo '</div>';
echo '</br>';

echo '<div id="tabellaProgetti" name="tabellaProgetti" class="tabellaDati">';
stampaTabellaProgetto();
echo '</div>';
```

Where can I change stampaTabellaProgetto() for the HTML of the table it do nothing. I have the table with the right style etc but no arrow for sorting and no error in console.

the `$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
        theme : 'blue'
    });`
Is just after the document ready.

Comment: Dude, don't echo your entire HTML page. Close the PHP tag and write your HTML normally. It's way better. It looks better in your text editor / IDE. And probably consumes less of your servers.

Comment: So i have a DIV printed with an echo called content, if i put the direct html code of the table in it works, but if i use my index.js and load  `$('#content').load('home.php'); ` the html ( still printed with echos ) it do nothing

Comment: I know it but not my entire project just editing the sorting ahhaha

Comment: write the code of table sorter in the ajax call, after html code is displayed.

Comment: If you're loading from another page using $.load, try this instead: `$('#content').load('home.php', function() { /*Your code here*/     });`

Comment: The function will run only after the entire table is loaded.

Comment: It works now thx Phiter Fernandes !!